# Harmonic functions that uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u_k$ be continuous on $\overline\Omega$, $u_k$ harmonic in $\Omega$. Suppose $u_k|\partial\Omega$ converge uniformly. Then $u_k$ converge uniformly in $\Omega$.

The hint is using Maximum Principle.

**My attempt**:

By Poisson Integral foumula:

$u_k(x)=\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial G}{\partial n}(x,y)u_k(y)ds(y)$. Then let $k$ goes to infinity. The RHS is harmonic so $u(x)$ is harmonic in $\Omega$.

**My question**:
 I didn't use maximum principle.

I have been thinking about it for several hours and I didn't figure a thing about maximum principle？

Can anyone help me with some answers or clues? That will be really helpful!

**Thanks a lot!:)**

Comment: What is assumed about the boundary of $\Omega$? To take normal derivative of $G$, you at least need the normal vector. With Maximum principle you don't have to worry about that. Just apply it to $u_k-u_l$ to show that the sequence is uniformly Cauchy.

Comment: @CareBear The original problem is in a Ball. Then normal vector is just $y/R$. But then there is a conclusion, says it is also true in $\Omega$ by using maximum principle. Then I am confused. I thought $\frac{\partial G}{\partial n}$ is always harmonic? Is that wrong? :)

Comment: For something to be harmonic, it first needs to be defined. To define normal derivative, we need to have normal vector. Not every domain has normal vectors at the boundary, only domains with smooth boundary do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u_k|_{\partial \Omega}$ is uniformly convergent it is uniformly Cauchy: if $$M_{j,k} = \max_{x \in \partial \Omega} |u_j(x) - u_k(x)|$$ then $M_{j,k} \to 0$ as $j,k \to \infty$.

Given two indices $j,k$ the difference $u_j - u_k$ is harmonic. For any $x_0 \in \Omega$ you have by the maximum principle $$u_j(x_0) - u_k(x_0) \le
\max_{x \in \overline \Omega} (u_j(x) - u_k(x)) = \max_{x \in \partial \Omega} (u_j(x) - u_k(x)) \le M_{j,k}.$$
Interchange the roles of $j$ and $k$ to obtain also $$u_k(x_0) - u_j(x_0) \le M_{j,k}.$$ Thus
$|u_j(x_0) - u_k(x_0)| \le M_{j,k}$ for all $x_0 \in \Omega$. This means that $\{u_k\}$ is uniformly Cauchy in $\Omega$, hence uniformly convergent.